# Adding highchart organization in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, next.js, organization

I have a problem regarding `highcharts` organization in reactjs/nextjs. I installed the npm package of highcharts-react-official and highcharts and import it in my component, still it gives me error that the organization is a missing module.

Here is the error:

```
Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=organization
 - missingModuleFor: organization
```

Here is what I've tried .

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

const HighChartsRender = () => {
  const options = {
    title: {
      text: "My chart",
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            descriptionFormatter: function (point) {
                var nodeName = point.toNode.name,
                    nodeId = point.toNode.id,
                    nodeDesc = nodeName === nodeId ? nodeName : nodeName + ', ' + nodeId,
                    parentDesc = point.fromNode.id;
                return point.index + '. ' + nodeDesc + ', reports to ' + parentDesc + '.';
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'organization',
        name: 'Highsoft',
        keys: ['from', 'to'],
        data: [
            ['Shareholders', 'Board'],
            ['Board', 'CEO'],
            ['CEO', 'CTO'],
            ['CEO', 'CPO'],
            ['CEO', 'CSO'],
            ['CEO', 'HR'],
            ['CTO', 'Product'],
            ['CTO', 'Web'],
            ['CSO', 'Sales'],
            ['HR', 'Market'],
            ['CSO', 'Market'],
            ['HR', 'Market'],
            ['CTO', 'Market']
        ],
        levels: [{
            level: 0,
            color: 'silver',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            height: 25
        }, {
            level: 1,
            color: 'silver',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            height: 25
        }, {
            level: 2,
            color: '#980104'
        }, {
            level: 4,
            color: '#359154'
        }],
        nodes: [{
            id: 'Shareholders'
        }, {
            id: 'Board'
        }, {
            id: 'CEO',
            title: 'CEO',
            name: 'Grethe Hjetland',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131126/Highsoft_03862_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'HR',
            title: 'HR/CFO',
            name: 'Anne Jorunn Fjærestad',
            color: '#007ad0',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131210/Highsoft_04045_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CTO',
            title: 'CTO',
            name: 'Christer Vasseng',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131120/Highsoft_04074_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CPO',
            title: 'CPO',
            name: 'Torstein Hønsi',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131213/Highsoft_03998_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CSO',
            title: 'CSO',
            name: 'Anita Nesse',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131156/Highsoft_03834_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'Product',
            name: 'Product developers'
        }, {
            id: 'Web',
            name: 'Web devs, sys admin'
        }, {
            id: 'Sales',
            name: 'Sales team'
        }, {
            id: 'Market',
            name: 'Marketing team',
            column: 5
        }],
        colorByPoint: false,
        color: '#007ad0',
        dataLabels: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        borderColor: 'white',
        nodeWidth: 65
    }],
    tooltip: {
        outside: true
    },
    exporting: {
        allowHTML: true,
        sourceWidth: 800,
        sourceHeight: 600
    }
  };

  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div className="content-area">
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HighChartsRender;
```

anyone tried to use the organization chart from highcharts in reactjs/nextjs ? .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the organization series requires two additional modules:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/organization.js"></script>
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization

You need to import those modules and initialize them: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3gu5bv?file=index.js

API: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react